# Leaving an APScheduler in a while True loop

Tags: python

I want to run a background job on my web server to do some database maintenance. I am looking at using `APScheduler` to do this.

I am planning on running the below code in a separate process to my main web server. I don't really want to tie the code to my web server.

Question: Is using `While True pass` at the end of a cron-like scheduler considered bad practice? How should it be done? (`time.sleep()`?)

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

@sched.interval_schedule(days=1)
def tick():
    # do a clean up job


while True:
    pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while True: pass` will consume 100 % of one CPU which is not something you want. I'm not familiar with APScheduler, but a quick look into [the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/#scheduler-configuration-options) reveals a `daemonic` option:

> Controls whether the scheduler thread is daemonic or not.
>
> If set to False, then the scheduler must be shut down explicitly when
>   the program is about to finish, or it will prevent the program from
>   terminating.
>
> If set to True, the scheduler will automatically terminate with the
>   application, but may cause an exception to be raised on exit.

Comment: I wasn't reading top correctly on my test. It really does use 100% of CPU. Thanks for the scheduler link to daemon mode - I missed that.